# Big Web Search - How to get the top results from all markets in a single query

Tags: bing, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the Bing Web Search provided by Microsofts Cognitive Services API suite.

I would like to make a single query that returns the top results from all markets. Essentially, I'm looking for something like this:

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=search_term&count=5&mkt=all
```

This would return the top 5 results from all available markets.

Is there a way to achieve this or would I need to query all markets individually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, [no finite answers in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-web-api-v5-reference#query-parameters).
If you read below, using cc, you can supply multiple values. However it's using the first, suggesting supplying multiple does not trigger different behavior.
Then later suggesting it's possible to do an aggregated market.

> cc - If you set this parameter, you must also specify the Accept-Language header. **Bing uses the first supported language** it finds in the specified languages and combines it with the country code to determine the market to return results for. If the languages list does not include a supported language, Bing finds the closest language and market that supports the request. Or, **Bing may use an aggregated or default market for the results**.

Again, this is using cc and Accept-Language header, instead of mkt and setLang.
Since the former can be called with multiple values, contrary to the latter.